# Add New Dependency Configuration That is Used For a Specific Task

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to setup an Android project, we have certain kind of tests (Tests A) that run differently from other tests (Tests B) that require their own dependencies that can't be included when Tests B run.

I'm trying to add a new configuration that extends androidTestCompile with this code in my build.gradle file:

```
configurations {
    myTestCompile.extendsFrom('androidTestCompile');
}
```

As per http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001741/ch04.html#DEPENDENCY-CONFIGURATIONS This doesn't work, it gives me an error 'method not found extendsFrom()'.

I then also don't know how to use certain configurations for a task.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the configuration first.

```
configurations {
    myTestCompile
    myTestCompile.extendsFrom androidTestCompile
}
```

**Edit**

You can then declare a test task that used that configuration.

```
task testB(type: Test) {
    classpath = configurations.myTestCompile
}
```